# OpenCV - return file type for a Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I have some code that I am using `cv::imdecode(Mat(buf), -1);`  where buf is a `vector` created from a `char*` to give me a Mat object from some raw data (in this case, I happen to know it is jpeg ahead of time).

is there anyway to get from the cv libraries what the original data type is of the `buf` (in this case I know its jpeg, but I dont want to hardcode that in) ? In other words, I would like to reverse this process with `cv::imencode()` and pass the same type of data back to the caller.

tldr: I want to be able to decode a raw data buffer into a cv::Mat, do some work, and then encode it back to a raw data buffer in it's original incoming format.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible with opencv. However if you are willing to make a custom version of highgui's loadsave.cpp it looks as though it would be fairly easy to achieve by changing imdecode so it  tells you the decoder index and  and then modifying imencode to allow you to pass this index (you would also need to modifer to the codec vectors initialization to make sure that the decoder and encode vectors match).

Comment: As far as I know, opencv can only be told of the format of the image rather than infer from the content. E.g. when getting input from file, you should specify the extension of the file and opencv learn the format from the filename extension.

Comment: That last part isn't right because I am passing imdecode a byte array essentially and it figures out it is jpg